# striptime output for Python is not showing time difference

Tags: python, sql

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  I am trying to output the difference between specific time pulled from SQL Server and current time in python:

```
ts = '2021-03-01T17:09:00.000+0000'
f = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
sql_data = datetime.strptime(ts, f)
now= datetime.strptime(ts, f)
delta = now- sql_data
```

The data I am pulling from SQL shows the correct date and time for 'sql_data' and 'now', but when I run the Python script the 'delta' output is '0:00:00'.

Comment: check your `now` line :-) it's again the same as `sql_data`. and `current` is not defined. Please, post [mre]

Comment: @buran delta = now-sql_data

Comment: again, `now` is the same as `sql_data`

Comment: @buran so should I create new variable?  What about the data I am getting from SQL?  How does python read that data and subtract the difference?..

Comment: Please, don't remove the code (or other important parts of your question), especially after you get answers that solve your problem. Also, please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it that you haven't defined current but now? And you have to define `now` properly. Try:
`delta = now - sql_data`

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
ts = '2021-03-01T17:09:00.000+0000'
f = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
sql_data = datetime.strptime(ts, f)
print(datetime.now(timezone.utc) - sql_data)

# or if you want a variable
now = datetime.now(timezone.utc) # this is UTC time
delta = now - sql_data
print(delta)
```

output

```
-16 days, 3:43:25.448494
-16 days, 3:43:25.448608
```

**Important note**  - because your DB data have timezone info, i.e. datetime object you create is offset-aware, you need to specify timezone info for now(). If you don't you will get naive datetime object and error `TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`. It's up to you to make sure you deal with timezone properly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `now` to be `current date & time`

```
ts = '2021-03-01T17:09:00.000+0000'
f = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
sql_data = datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, f)
now= datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)

delta = now - sql_data
```

`Delta: datetime.timedelta(-16, 13492, 464200)`